# Count how many characters from a column appear in another column

Tags: r

I am trying to count how many characters from column `expected` appear in column `read`.
They may appear in different order and they should not be counted twice.

For example, in this df

```
df <- tibble::tibble(expected=c("AL0","CP1","NM3","PK9","RM2"),
                     read=c("AL0X24",
                            "CXP44",
                            "MLN",
                            "KKRR9",
                            "22MMRRS"
                     ))
```

The result should be:

```
result <- c(3,2,2,2,3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An option with `str_extract/n_distinct`.  Wrap the `[`, `]` with the 'expected' column string using `paste`, extract all the characters that show the pattern in 'expected' from 'read' and count the number of distinct elements with `n_distinct`

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
with(df, sapply(str_extract_all(read, paste0("[", expected, "]")), n_distinct))
#[1] 3 2 2 2 3
```

---

Or another option with `str_replace_all` with `str_count`.  Here, we remove the duplicate characters in 'read' with `str_replace_all` and use that to count the characters in 'expected' by pasteing the `[`, and `]`

```
df %>% 
    mutate(Count = str_count(str_replace_all(read, "(\\w)\\1+", "\\1"), 
        str_c("[", expected, "]")))
# A tibble: 5 x 3
#  expected read    Count
#  <chr>    <chr>   <int>
#1 AL0      AL0X24      3
#2 CP1      CXP44       2
#3 NM3      MLN         2
#4 PK9      KKRR9       2
#5 RM2      22MMRRS     3
```

Comment: Alternate: `map` instead of `sapply` to keep it all tidyverse: `map(str_match_all(df$read, str_c("[", df$expected, "]")), n_distinct)`

Answer (score 2):

One option could be:

```
mapply(function(x, y) sum(x %in% unique(y)),
       x = strsplit(df$expected, ""),
       y = strsplit(df$read, ""))

[1] 3 2 2 2 3
```